# List of contracts bound to an address

Tags: ether, wallets, contract-invocation

Is it possible the view the list of all contracts an Ethereum address is bound to?

scenarios:

1. John deposited funds in many DEXs but can't remember which ones. John would like to see if his wallet has funds laying around
2. Billy interacted with EtherDelta/ForkDelta years ago, but Billy can't remember which coins he transferred

Comment: There's zapper.fi that works for defi projects. I don't know if there's something similar for old dexes.

Comment: @Ismael thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for old dexes

Comment: https://deltabalances.github.io/ does it but is limited